# How to decompose a 3x3 matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix:

```
mat = ([0.81, 0.63, 0.45],
       [0.63, 0.49, 0.35],
       [0.45, 0.35, 0.25])
```

I know that it can be decomposed into two identical vectors LL'

```
L = [0.9, 0.7, 0.5]
```

But is there any python code that allows me to decompose a matrix in this way?

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you know it can be factorized like that, you could just square-root the diagonal.

Comment: but what if it is a big matrix and I'm not sure if I can just take the square root of the diagonal?

Comment: If it's a big matrix, then... you take the square root of the diagonal, just like with a small matrix. Why would big ones need different treatment?

Comment: it just so happens this matrix is easily decomposable. I just want to know if it's another 3x3 matrix, would there be a way to decompose it in a similar manner.